# Custom ionic/cordva plugin for iOS. Method not defined in plugin error

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, ionic-framework

I am writing my custom plugin in ionic for iOS in swift but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Method 'initialize:' not defined in Plugin 'RabbitMqPlugin'
```

I have searched in order to find solution but I could not figure out what is the problem.

Below is my code.

**plugin.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="cordova-plugin-rabbitmq"
    version="0.0.1">
    <name>RabbitMqPlugin</name>
    <js-module src="www/plugin.js" name="RabbitMqPlugin">
       <clobbers target="RabbitMqPlugin" />
    </js-module>

<!-- ios -->
<dependency id="cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support" />
<dependency id="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" />
<platform name="ios">
    <pods-config ios-min-version="9.0" use-frameworks="true">
    </pods-config>
    <pod name="RMQClient" />

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="RabbitMqPlugin">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/ios/CDVHttpRequest.swift" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/CDVRabbitMq.swift" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/CDVRabbitMqPlugin.swift" />
</platform>
</plugin>
```

**plugin.js** file in www folder:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

var PLUGIN_NAME = 'RabbitMqPlugin';

 var RabbitMqPlugin = {
    initialize: function(phrase, cb) {
    exec(cb, null, PLUGIN_NAME, 'initialize', [phrase]);
 }
};

module.exports = RabbitMqPlugin;
```

**CDVRabbitMqPlugin.swift** file in src/ios folder:

```
import Foundation

@objc(RabbitMqPlugin) class RabbitMqPlugin : CDVPlugin {
var mRabbit:rabbitMQ!;

@objc(initialize:)
func initialize(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand){
    var pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
        status: CDVCommandStatus_ERROR
    );

    let token = command.arguments[0] as! String;

    if (token.characters.count > 0) {
        mRabbit = rabbitMQ(mToken: token);

        pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
            status: CDVCommandStatus_ERROR
        );
    }

    self.commandDelegate!.send(
        pluginResult, 
        callbackId: command.callbackId
    )
  }
}
```

I have installed the cordova-plugin-add-swift-support module in order to support swift.
I have added custom plugin ionic plugin for Android and I implemented to my ionic project successfully.

Hope you can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feature in the plugin.xml is wrong, it should be

```
<feature name="RabbitMqPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="RabbitMqPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

Also, if you are not naming the classes with CDVClassname, don't name the files that contain those classes starting with CDV, not sure if that will fail in Swift, but better name the Swift files with the same name the class they contain

Comment: Yes that was it thank you very much.
Now I am getting this: THREAD WARNING: ['RabbitMqPlugin'] took '20.425049' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

Also in the inspections I get this: Failed to load resource: unsupported URL  gap://ready

Comment: That's just a warning. If you want to get rid of it you can use a background thread, see the threading section of the plugin guide. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html#threading. About the unsupported URL, are you using a WKWebView plugin? Do you have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your index.html? In case you have it, can you share it? Do other plugins work?

Comment: I have added the webview plugin. Yes I have added the security meta tag and here it is: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">     Yes the other plugin works.

Comment: If you are using `WKWebView` plugin, then remove `gap://ready` from the CSP as that is only needed for `UIWebView`

Comment: I have the following plugin installed: 
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"

Comment: Yeah, that uses WKWebView, try removing `gap://ready` from the CSP

Comment: What do you mean CSP?

Comment: Content-Security-Policy. Change it to  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">`

Comment: I want to make more than one callbacks in iOS (swift).
I am waiting for messages in my swift code asynchronously and every time when I receive message I want to make callback  in order to receive my message in my Ionic code. Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: This is Objective-C code, but you have to do the same with Swift. You have to set the result's keepCallback to true/yes `[result setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];`. You will also need to save the `command.callbackId` in a variable to use the same value every time

Comment: let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult( 
                    status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, 
                    messageAs: msg 
                ); 
                
                self.commandDelegate!.send( 
                    pluginResult, 
                    callbackId: command.callbackId 
                ) 

The above is my code. Where I have to put the setKeepCallbackBool?

Comment: before the send, something like `pluginResult.setKeepCallbackAsBool(true)`

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for the help :)